# Format the text of UIImagePickerController's "Cancel" and "Choose" buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to format (change font type and size) the placeholder text of the `Cancel` and the `Choose` buttons in the `UIImagePickerController`. I've checked several questions, but couldn't find a related answer that could be good as a starting point. Already checked Apple's PhotoPicker sample, but it's too complex for this purpose, i need something lightweight just to edit the fonts.

This is my image picker's code:

```
 if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary] == YES) {

        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        imagePicker.delegate = self;

        imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

        // this line does nothing
        imagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `UIAppearance` proxies for this:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIImagePickerController class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:14.0] } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

will change the font for the bar buttons in a `UIImagePickerController` to `AmericanTypewriter` size 14.

Comment: Where should i call this? Inside the `viewDidLoad` or where I configure the picker?

Comment: @vv88 Any time before the picker is presented. It's app-wide, so it's common to include appearance proxy stuff in the app delegate.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the Appearance Proxy (ie, if you want to set it for just one controller), you can also modify the specific controller's items before it's presented:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];

    [items addObjectsFromArray:viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems];
    [items addObjectsFromArray:viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems];

    NSDictionary *font = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:16]};

    for (UIBarButtonItem *item in items) {
        [item setTitleTextAttributes:font forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think my question was a bit incorrect, I thought of the choose & cancel button what are on the bottom, where you can zoom into the picked image. Is it not the picker view?

Comment: The picker varies a little bit from one iOS version to another but I think you're referring to the taken picture confirmation screen. Could you add a screenshot to be sure?

Comment: @Rivera You are right, I'm referring to the taken picture confirmation screen. I believed it's the image picker..

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
 NSString *classname  = @"PLUIImageViewController";
    if([[[viewController class] description] isEqualToString:classname])
      {
       NSLog(@"Found the damn controller");
       viewController.navigationItem.title = @"Rat";
       NSDictionary *attrsDictionary1 = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:10.0],NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]};
       //NSDictionary *attrsDictionary =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:10] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
       NSAttributedString *attrString =[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Got Me" attributes:attrsDictionary1];
       [[UIButton appearance]setAttributedTitle:attrString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       //[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textTitleOptions];
       [[UIButton appearance] titleLabel].textColor = [UIColor redColor];
      }
}
```

I hope this might help you..

Answer (score 0):

Since `UIImagePickerController` is a type of Navigation controller, you're also setting yourself as the `UINavigationController` delegate. Then :

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
 //Write your code here for setting the color
}
```